# Java client to WCF web service - first element of 2d arrray parameter is dropped

Tags: wcf, apache-axis, java-ws

**Update**

I have posted soap generated by java WCF clients. The WCF one works fine.
Have also posted the schema of the message for the method from the WSDL that was used to generate both clients. One potential isuse with the java client is that it looks like it should have ArrayOfArrayOfRequestParameter for the outer array instead of ArrayOfRequestParameter.

The client is generated by eclispe which seems to run the wsimport utility. On the java side I can see that the parameter requests has 2 elements in both requests[0] and requests[1] but the server get an empty array in requests[0] and 2 elements in requests[1]. Am guessing this is something to do with how array bounds are interpreted - maybe there is some attribute I can set in the WCF data contract?

The signature of the method is as follows:

```
[OperationContract]
Response[] SendMultiPartRequest(string serviceName, RequestParameter[][] requests);
```

Here is the data contract for RequestParameter:

```
[DataContract]
public class RequestParameter
{
    private string _key;
    private string _value;

    public RequestParameter()
    {
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string Key
    {
        get { return _key; }
        set { _key = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set { _value = value; }
    }
}
```

Here is web service config

```
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="FooServiceBehaviour" name="FooService.WebService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicConfig" contract="FooService.IFooService"
        bindingNamespace="http://foo.com/FooService"
    />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:10000/FooService"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>

<bindings>
   <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="basicConfig" useDefaultWebProxy="true" 
         maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      </binding>
   </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<!-- For debugging purposes set the includeExceptionDetailInFaults attribute to true -->
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="FooServiceBehaviour">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True"/>
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Here is the soap request generated by the java client:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Body>
  <SendMultiPartRequest xmlns="http://foo.com/FooService">
    <serviceName>uploadTrade</serviceName>
      <requests>
        <ArrayOfRequestParameter>
            <ArrayOfRequestParameter>
                <Key>a</Key>
                <Value>100</Value>
            </ArrayOfRequestParameter>
            <ArrayOfRequestParameter>
                <Key>b</Key>
                <Value>200</Value>
            </ArrayOfRequestParameter>
        </ArrayOfRequestParameter>
        <ArrayOfRequestParameter>
            <RequestParameter>
                <Key>a</Key>
                <Value>100</Value>
            </RequestParameter>
            <RequestParameter>
                <Key>b</Key>
                <Value>200</Value>
            </RequestParameter>
        </ArrayOfRequestParameter>
    </requests>
  </SendMultiPartRequest>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Here is the soap for a WCF client which works fine with the server.

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Body>
    <SendMultiPartRequest xmlns="http://foo.com/FooService">
    <serviceName>service1</serviceName>
    <requests xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <ArrayOfRequestParameter>
        <RequestParameter>
            <Key>a</Key>
            <Value>100</Value>
        </RequestParameter>
        <RequestParameter>
            <Key>b</Key>
            <Value>200</Value>
        </RequestParameter>
    </ArrayOfRequestParameter>
    <ArrayOfRequestParameter>
        <RequestParameter>
            <Key>a</Key>
            <Value>100</Value>
        </RequestParameter>
        <RequestParameter>
            <Key>b</Key>
            <Value>200</Value>
        </RequestParameter>
    </ArrayOfRequestParameter>
</requests>
</SendMultiPartRequest>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Here is a fragment of wsdl that defines the message for the function

```
<element name="SendMultiPartRequest">
    <complexType>
        <sequence>
            <element minOccurs="0" name="serviceName" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
            <element minOccurs="0" name="requests" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfArrayOfRequestParameter"/>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
</element>
```

Comment: Try to intercept the raw request when the call is made from your client to the service using Fiddler and see if your request[0] has 18 elements and if it does then the problem might be on the server side which can be found using Tracing (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx)

Comment: please publish the soap here. also write a wcf client to this service and publish it soap also. then you can compare them

Comment: @Rajesh - I have posted soap from the java client and a WCF one also. Look like java uses the wrong name for the outer array - any ideas about where to look next? I've started looking at the generated code for the service stub.

Comment: Have you tried the same using SOAP UI tools. Try to take the wsdl and use it for both Java and .NET Clients to make sure that the problem is with the client generating different SOAP request. Using SOAP UI should be easy